# Creating An Artificial Universe

Tags: artificial-intelligence, simulation

This is a general question and one that has bugged me for a long time.

I want to start working on an artificial universe, not something too ambitious but more of a basic concept. What I have in mind is a simulation that has a sense of time, has physics rules, some beings that interact with each other and are able to learn to some extent, in a top-down, 2D world. In addition to this, it might have a visualization of what is going on, like a game.

I didn't succeed in finding a work or guide on this topic. The questions are:

What should be the approach to building such a simulation?
Are there any resources that can help me get started?

Comment: If are able to program it shouldn't be that are. You just need to find a way to render graphics in your fav programming language (for python I recommend pygame for projects like that). you can find lots of examples if you enter sth. like evolution/ecosystem simulator/ai evolution into google (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myJ7YOZGkv0)

Comment: (@plshelp: I fail to parse `If are able to program it shouldn't be that are` to any avail.)

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at Conway's game of life for inspiration. You can start with simple entities and simple rules describing how each entity reacts to neighboring entities and the current timestamp and you'll be amazed at the complexity that'll arise.

Comment: @droptop Thanks I will make sure to look at that.

Comment: @plshelp That is helpful thanks. But I am looking for something more structured, like a book, paper etc.

Comment: @Rookie like this https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2017-11-30/evolving-simple-organisms-using-a-genetic-algorithm-and-deep-learning/  ? To learn visualization I would look at this tutorial https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/ . Now there are "papers" on this topic like https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/my_papers/sticky_feet.pdf and presentations https://chakazul.github.io/How%20to%20Evolve%20Life.pdf put they usually don't cover implementation details

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify the programming languages that you know and if you have something specific in mind like Cellular automata or e.g. AI agents that walk around eat food and develop via a genetic algorithm

Comment: @plshelp I am competent in many languages but for this project, what I consider are C++ or Python. What I have in mind is 'AI agents that walk around eat food and develop via a genetic algorithm' exactly (and random mutations if I can add). I have knowledge of linear machine learning techniques but no deep learning knowledge (Only some signal processing knowledge), yet.

Comment: @greybeard: I think the phrase “If are able to program it shouldn’t be that are” could render as “If you are able to program it shouldn’t be that hard”. Just a guess.